# How can I get last element and length in bigint[] form postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in postgresql like:

```
Column |   Type   | Modifiers 
--------+----------+-----------
 id     | bigint   | not null
 nodes  | bigint[] | not null
 tags   | text[]   |
```

And some example data:

```
    id    |   nodes    
----------+------------
 25373389 |  {1}
 25373582 |  {1,2,3,2,6}
 25373585 |  {1,276,3,2}
```

I want to get last element and length of `nodes`,so I expect result is:

```
    id    |   nodes    |   last     |   length    
----------+------------+------------+------------
 25373389 |  {1}       |     1      |     1
 25373582 | {1,2,3,2,6}|     6      |     5
 25373585 | {1,276,3,2}|     2      |     4
```

I use follow code to get first element,but I can't use `nodes[-1]` to get last element.

```
select id,nodes[1] from table limit 3;
```

How can I get it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `array_length`

```
select nodes[array_length(nodes,1)] as last, array_length(nodes,1) as length from t;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=a04ce2c06827c6b09271c37fe4488de2)

Comment: Alternatively you can use `cardinality(nodes)`  instead of `array_length(nodes,1)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . Is there a reason to prefer `cardinality()` over `array_length()`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I find it easier to read and more intuitive as most arrays only have one dimension (I have seen people being confused about the second parameter)